# Some times response not sending when sequelize error occur (Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[image]when i pass wrong QueryParams value like minus value. occur **Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-8, 4' at line 1** that situation **not get response from server**

```
http://localhost:500/XXX/getXXX?currentPage=-1&numPerPage=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely global error was not handled properly. Try adding it to your routes.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('internal server error');
})
```